# Dreamstime - payment options

Tags: payment

I´m a new user in Dreamstime service (http://dreamstime.com). I need to download from there 5 images in the highest quality, so I´m thinking about *Subscription* variant instead of buying credits (http://www.dreamstime.com/credits).

Does anyone experience with that, if there is any restriction for image quality in Subscription variant? I have found no info about that. It´s cheaper of about 50% in comparing with buying credits.

Thanks for info and sharing your experience.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is not about programming. Please use for that https://superuser.com/